# SAP HANA XS Advanced CORS configuration

Tags: angularjs, angular, cors, hana

​Can someone tell me how to set CORS filter on XS advanced server. Currently all request calls from client application(angular) are rejected with message:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

XSA don't have .xsaccess file like XS server. By default XSA should accept all CORS requests but this is not the case.

Comment: Seems like the docs at https://help.hana.ondemand.com/hana_cloud_platform_mobile_services/frameset.htm?13fae79829734b318bc6edb0ae8fd5a4.html might be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your client is angular app and you have some other "backend" app deployed on XSA.

First of all, your "backend" app (java, nodejs,...) should be part of multi target application. When you build this app, you will get .mtar (mulri target archive) which then should be deployed to XSA.

Also you need to create one more module as part of MTA. The module/app type should be `html5` type, and commont practice is to call it `web`

`web` module acts as an application router and there is a file `xs-app.json` where you can specify route rules and also cors settings. It is a useful feature because you can manage the securty in that way.

Comment: Much appreciated my friend but Bane fixed it few months ago.